Who told Judah that Tamar was pregnant?
Genesis 38:24 YLT

And it cometh to pass about three months [after], that it is declared to Judah, saying, ‘Tamar thy daughter-in-law hath committed fornication; and also, lo, she hath conceived by fornication:’ and Judah saith, ‘Bring her out — and she is burnt.’

Who told Judah that Tamar committed fornication, and how would that person know she had conceived by fornication?

Her appearance (at the end of three months) was what precipitated the discovery of Tamar seeking her personal rights.

Please check scripture in context to understand your question before posting, and then include that scripture within the context of your question based upon the clarity of what you are seeking to find. You may find an answer prior to posting a question here and if you don't find the answer this way, this sort of a clear contextual process when shared with us makes the question better understood and hopefully more easily answered.


"Who told Judah that Tamar committed fornication?" - Given verses 11 and 19, most likely someone from her father's house. Perhaps her father told Judah himself, perhaps gossip reached Judah second- or third-hand. We aren't told, or really even given a hint, which indicates that it probably isn't important. Who exactly told him isn't the point.
"How would that person know she had conceived by fornication?" - this seems obvious. Her first two husbands died (verses 6-10), considerable time has passed (11-12), she's still unmarried and she's pregnant. While we don't know how long exactly passed between verse 10 and verse 13, it's clearly long enough that the pregnancy can't be the result of legitimate relations with her husband.

